# Emissive particles don't show up in reflections

Tags: particles, reflection

I set up a plane, that emmits particles, that emmit orange light. I made another object, that has a metallic 0 material. I want the particles to reflect in the shiny object, but they don't. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Eevee? If you are using Eevee, you should try turning on "Screen Space Reflections" in the side bar.